# Client Authentication request auto cancelled in Apple watch

Tags: tls1.2, ssl-client-authentication, watchapp, watchos-7

I am trying to make TLS request for client authentication from a watch.

I found that the connection was cancelled immediately after the client (iwatch) provide the client certificate, by calling completionHandler(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeUseCredential, credential).

The error which I got is

```
"Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "cancelled" UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=serverurl, NSErrorFailingURLKey=serverurl, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
  "LocalDataTask <BB419DCD-C248-4F3E-8EEB-9AF3AA1A9256>.<1>",
  "LocalDataPDTask <BB419DCD-C248-4F3E-8EEB-9AF3AA1A9256>.<1>",
  "LocalDataTask <BB419DCD-C248-4F3E-8EEB-9AF3AA1A9256>.<1>"
), _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <BB419DCD-C248-4F3E-8EEB-9AF3AA1A9256>.<1>, NSLocalizedDescription=cancelled}"
```

.

The request is cancelled by client itself....Its not reaching to server.

When I tried to **run the same code on a iphone, it succeed.**

I tried to run this api from both types of watch app independent and dependant.

**Apart from this TLS request, all other requests work fine on the watch.**

Is there anything specifically need to be configured for the watch for client authentication?

Is client authentication not supported in Apple watch? If that is the case It should even not support the api like SecPKS12Import then.